# App Delegate's application:didReceiveLocalNotification: not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

In my app delegate the method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification: (UILocalNotification *)notification` is never called.

This is how I create the notification:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
// set UUID, which we will store in userDefaults for later
NSMutableDictionary *myUserInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *uuid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
[myUserInfo setValue:uuid forKey:KEY_UUID];
[myUserInfo setValue:@"month" forKey:KEY_UNIT];
[myUserInfo setObject:@YES forKey:KEY_RESCHEDULE];
NSInteger row = [_wurmProphylaxePickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
switch (row) {
    case 0:
        [myUserInfo setValue:@2 forKey:KEY_FREQUENCY];
        break;
    case 1:
        [myUserInfo setValue:@4 forKey:KEY_FREQUENCY];
        break;
    case 2:
        [myUserInfo setValue:@6 forKey:KEY_FREQUENCY];
        break;
    default:
        [myUserInfo setValue:@4 forKey:KEY_FREQUENCY];
        break;
}
notification.userInfo = myUserInfo;
// calculate date for next notification, depends on the user's selection
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *myComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[myComps setMinute:1];
notification.fireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:myComps toDate:today options:0];
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
notification.alertBody = @"My alertBody";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

And this is in my app delegates, but is never called:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    BOOL repeat = [[userInfo objectForKey:KEY_RESCHEDULE] boolValue];
    if (repeat)
    {
        NSInteger frequency = (NSInteger)[userInfo objectForKey:KEY_FREQUENCY];
        NSString *unit = (NSString *)[userInfo objectForKey:KEY_UNIT];
        NSString *uuid = (NSString *)[userInfo objectForKey:KEY_UUID];

        // calculate date for next notification
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *myComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        if ([unit isEqualToString:@"month"]) {
            //[myComps setMonth:frequency];
            [myComps setMinute:frequency];
        } else {

        }

        // create new notification
        UILocalNotification *newNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        newNotification.fireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:myComps toDate:today options:0];
        newNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        newNotification.alertAction = notification.alertAction;
        newNotification.alertBody = notification.alertBody;
        newNotification.userInfo = notification.userInfo;

        // schedule it
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:newNotification];     
    }
}
```

tested on iOS 8, not sure about iOS 7...

Comment: Did you register for the notification first? See [Registering for Notification Types in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4).

Comment: yes, i do, and the permission alert is displayed, and the notification is displayed, but the delegate method isn't called

Comment: ... And the app is in foreground when this notification comes in?

Comment: no, it is in the background

Comment: ok. i see. If u post it as an answer, i will accept it. tx Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is not active when the notification fires,  you would handle this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as illustrated by this example from the *Handling Local and Remote Notifications* section of the [Local and Push Notifications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        NSString *itemName = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:ToDoItemKey];
        [viewController displayItem:itemName];  // custom method
        app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
    }
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called if the app was active when the notification fired.

Comment: But what will happen, if the app is in the background, and the notification is displayed to the user, but the user is not tapping it, there is no method called in the app delegate?

Comment: If the user chooses to not click on the local notification while the app is not running, then no method will be called. From a developer's perspective, that's a little annoying, but from an end user's prospective, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: So if I want to instrument the fact that a localNotification was clicked to open the app, I should just put that in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" right?

Comment: Yep, unless you have newer custom action buttons, in which case `handleActionWithIdentifier` is called. And if the app is already running `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called. Also, remember to register for local notifications with `registerUserNotificationSettings`. All of this is described in the link provided in my answer.